# Cpanel API Access denied

Tags: php, api, cpanel

I'm using XML api 2

```
$xmlapi = new xmlapi('MY IP Address');
$xmlapi->password_auth("root",'My Cpanel password');
$xmlapi->set_output("json");

$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
print $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpopswithdisk" );
```

But it's giving this error.

```
{"cpanelresult":{"apiversion":"2","error":"Access denied","data":{"reason":"Access denied","result":"0"},"type":"text"}}
```

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your port settings -

`$xmlapi->set_port(2083); //2082 if not using secure connection`